# Mongoose, express returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I have read a lot of similar issues talking for pluralization on the model's name by default on mongoose. Though it doesn't seem to work on this case. The problem is that it returns an empty array. My local mongoDB contains 2 documents in the "userData" collection that they look like this:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5dcd0582587ac600ec9323a5"),
        "name" : "John",
        "surname" : "Doe",
        "team" : "CE",
        "project" : "Project1",
        "id" : "2"
}
```

Then this is my model `User.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({
    name: 'String',
    surname: 'String',
    team: 'String',
    project: 'String',
    id: 'String'
}, { collection: 'UserData' });

module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

and this is my routes `userRoutes.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('user');

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.get(`/`, async (req, res) => {
    let users = await User.find();
    return res.status(200).send(users);
  });

  app.post(`/user`, async (req, res) => {
    let user = await User.create(req.body);
    return res.status(201).send({
      error: false,
      user
    })
  })

  app.put(`/user/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body);
    return res.status(202).send({
      error: false,
      user
    })

  });

  app.delete(`/user/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let user = await User.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    return res.status(202).send({
      error: false,
      user
    })

  })

}
```

Finally this is my starting point `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose'); /*-- Import the mongoose module --*/
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
require('./models/User');

const app = express();

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/users', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true })  
  .then(() => console.log('Database Connection Succesful'))
  .catch(err => console.log('Database Connection Error0'));

var db = mongoose.connection;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

require('./routes/userRoutes')(app);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  })

}

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app running on port ${PORT}`)
});
```

Then my return is an empty array `[]`. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema code, you need to define field types like  **name: String**  instead of  **name: "String"**.

Your schema must be like this:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    surname: String,
    team: String,
    project: String,
    id: String
  },
  { collection: "UserData" }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
```

Also you already created user model, so  in userRoute there is no need to do like this:

```
const User = mongoose.model('user');
```

You just need to correctly import User model like this in userRoute.

```
const User = require("../models/User"); // you can change the path if it is not correct
```

Lastly to enable the json for post data, you need to add this line to your index.js:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

With these changes, you can create a user with this url http://localhost:3000/user using a json body like this:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "surname": "Doe",
    "team": "CE",
    "project": "Project1",
    "id": "2"
}
```

This will give a result like this:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "user": {
        "_id": "5dce7f8c07d72d4af89dec57",
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "team": "CE",
        "project": "Project1",
        "id": "2",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

At this point you will have a collection UserData.

And when you send a get request to http://localhost:5000 url, you will get the users like:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5dce75a91cbb4e5f7c5ebfb3",
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe",
        "team": "CE",
        "project": "Project1",
        "id": "2",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
```

Comment: @FotiosTragopoulos you must create a user

Comment: Then you will be able to get users

Comment: The first code block in the question is one of the users, I added it there as an example of the db.userData.find() response on the mongoDB shell.

Comment: @FotiosTragopoulos please create a new user with the new code, and try to get users

Comment: @FotiosTragopoulos I updated the question to show steps what should be done to make it work.

Comment: The response I get on Postman when I send the json body you added is this: `{
    "error": false,
    "user": {
        "_id": "5dce821c0b35af58a43b938c",
        "__v": 0
    }
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202395/discussion-between-suleymansah-and-fotios-tragopoulos).